# Error using JS to resize images in IE

Tags: javascript, css, image, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I use javascript to resize an image onload.  The below code works great in chrome and firefox, but does not work in internet explorer 11 (or any version).

```
function imgWidth(){
        var width = document.getElementById('homework').offsetWidth;
        document.getElementById('image').style="width: "+(940-width)+";";
        var height = document.getElementById('image-container').offsetHeight;
        var imgheight = document.getElementById('image').offsetHeight;
        if(imgheight > height){
            document.getElementById('image').style="top: -"+((imgheight - height)/2)+";width: "+(940-width)+";";
        }
        document.getElementById('image-container').style="width: "+(940-width)+";margin-left:"+(width+40)+";";
        }
```

Below is the html segment that calls the JS function:

```
<figure id="image-container">
    <img id="image" onload="imgWidth()" src="http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/full_width_feature/public/thumbnails/image/pia21376d.jpg" title="This image of a crescent Jupiter and the iconic Great Red Spot was created by a citizen scientist (Roman Tkachenko) using data from Juno's JunoCam instrument." />
</figure>
```

Here is an image of the webspace as it appears in chrome.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lq60N.png 
Notice, it resizes with respect to the width of the container on the left.  The code also crops the image so it is vertically aligned within its container.
The id "image" corresponds to an img tag, while "image-container" corresponds to the figure element around the img tag. 
Again, I am trying to make my code compatible with IE.
Here is how the image loads in IE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzwsS.png

Answer (score 0):

I ended up replacing the existing javascript with jQuery and it works now.

for example instead of

```
document.getElementById('homework').offsetWidth;
```

I used

```
$("#homework").outerWidth();
```

And instead of

```
document.getElementById('image').style="width: "+(940-width)+";";
```

I used

```
$("#image").css("width",(940-width));
```